# Return the sheet name of a dynamic name range in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following problem:

I have a dynamic namerange named **TestDym**.

I am trying to retrieve the name of the worksheet that this namerange belongs through vba.

I know that you can only refer to a namerange with the following structure:

```
Range("TestDym")
```

However, I cannot get the sheet name of this namerange.

Is it possible?

Regards

Thanasis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to return the "Scope" of the name range, you can use:

```
Names("TestDym").Parent.Name
```

- If TestDym is a workbook level name, then the result will return the workbook name.
- If TestDym is a worksheet level name, then the result will return the worksheet name.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Kudos for going through the way-underused `Names` collection, which is *the* right way to do this and end up with explicit code that reads like it's accessing a defined name.

Comment: Thanks! I was only typing Names("TestDym").Parent and not Names("TestDym").Parent.Name.

Answer (score 2):

```
Range("TestDym").Worksheet.Name
```

Comment: One reason to use .worksheet is you'll have intellisense auto complete for .name

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the name of the sheet your range is on.

```
Range("TestDym").Parent.Name
```

Comment: Any particular reason for not using .Worksheet, @braX?

Comment: Either will work. What you will discover about VBA is that there are many different ways of doing the same thing.